# Printing rhomboid using scanner in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

```
Enter edge length of your rhomboid: 5
Here is your rhomboid:


    *****
   *****
  *****
 *****
*****
```

I need to print that rhomboid with scanner. I get like: `* * * * * *`

My code was like that normally I'm not that bad but i couldn't even do the first line:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class rhomboid {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter edge lenght of your rhomboid: ");
        int edgelenght = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Here is your rhomboid:");

        while(edgelenght > 0){
            System.out.print(" ");
            System.out.print("*");
            edgelenght--;
```

Comment: Could you post your current code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your code will just print 1D output..
Output:- *****

So, to solve this you need two loops one for row and column.Now a little modification in 2D printing for rhombus is, first now there must be gap of 4 spaces before printing,it can be achieved by using one more variable k as shown below.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter edge lenght of your rhomboid: ");
    int edgelenght = scan.nextInt();
    int k = edgelenght - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < edgelenght; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < k + edgelenght; j++) {
            if (j < k) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            } else {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
        }
        k--;
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: @eko56 :- If my solution solved your problem , please don't forget to mark it as "ACCEPTED" and vote if you feel it was helpful.
Marking accepted will help others having similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

What you get is what you wrote in your code.

```
while(edgelenght > 0){
    System.out.print(" ");
    System.out.print("*");
    edgelenght--;
}
```

will print edgelenght times a space " " and after that a "*".

What you want is something like this:

```
for(int line = 0; line < edgeLength; line++){
    // in line 0 print 4 spaces (5-1), in line 3 print 1 (5-1-3), in line 4 (the last one) print 0
    for(int space = 0; space < edgeLength - line - 1; space++){
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    for(int asterix = 0; asterix < edgeLength; asterix++){
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    // print a newline
    System.out.println("");
}
```

You need to first loop over the lines.
For every line you need a loop to print spaces. And one to print *.